# Getting an error from console when using mdIcon

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Angular is throwing an error when I'm using mdIcon. Below is the code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdIcon} from '@angular2-material/icon';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <md-toolbar>
      <md-icon class="demo-toolbar-icon">menu</md-icon>
      <span>Default Toolbar</span>

      <span class="demo-fill-remaining"></span>

      <md-icon>code</md-icon>
    </md-toolbar>`,
    directives: [MdIcon,MdToolbar],

})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for MdIconRegistry!
>   Error: DI Exception
>           at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.ts:14)
>           at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.ts:53)
>           at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.ts:85)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:844)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:873)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:835)
>           at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:632)
>           at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:19)
>           at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.createInternal (AppComponent.template.js:141)
>           at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)

Can anyone please help me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update for the 2.0.0 release using material alpha 8-4:

You need to include `MdIconRegistry` as a provider in your app.modules.ts file.  Here is a functional example:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdButtonToggleModule } from '@angular2-material/button-toggle';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
import { MdGridListModule } from '@angular2-material/grid-list';
import { MdIconModule, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular2-material/input';
import { MdListModule } from '@angular2-material/list';
import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular2-material/menu';
import { MdProgressBarModule } from '@angular2-material/progress-bar';
import { MdProgressCircleModule } from '@angular2-material/progress-circle';
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular2-material/radio';
import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
import { MdSliderModule } from '@angular2-material/slider';
import { MdSlideToggleModule } from '@angular2-material/slide-toggle';
import { MdTabsModule } from '@angular2-material/tabs';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdTooltipModule } from '@angular2-material/tooltip';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,

        MdButtonModule,
        MdButtonToggleModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdCheckboxModule,
        MdGridListModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdInputModule,
        MdListModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdProgressBarModule,
        MdProgressCircleModule,
        MdRadioModule,
        MdSidenavModule,
        MdSliderModule,
        MdSlideToggleModule,
        MdTabsModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdTooltipModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MdIconRegistry
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Don't forget to install hammerjs + typings and add `import 'hammerjs';` to your main.ts file if you want to use the md-slide-toggle, and md-slider modules.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me, but do not forget import HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)  The import for the HttpModule is there. or did I miss something...

Answer (score 7):

You need to list it in `providers` or `viewProviders` and register some icons or iconsets

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MdIcon} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <md-toolbar>
      <md-icon class="demo-toolbar-icon">menu</md-icon>
      <span>Default Toolbar</span>

      <span class="demo-fill-remaining"></span>

      <md-icon>code</md-icon>
    </md-toolbar>`,
    directives: [MdIcon,MdToolbar],
    viewProviders: [MdIconRegistry],
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry) {
        mdIconRegistry
            .addSvgIcon('thumb-up', '/demo-app/icon/assets/thumbup-icon.svg')
            .addSvgIconSetInNamespace('core', '/demo-app/icon/assets/core-icon-set.svg')
            .registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where this variable 'MdIconRegistry' come from?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/1efbbb934f28e0aa92e7827ba1ae73e87beeb7a3/src/demo-app/main.ts#L7

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just import the MaterialRootModule in your app.module.ts:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
```

Comment: This will work as of [2.0.0-alpha.9](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha.9).

Answer (score 0):

Import Http.
  Visit https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-material2/ZEHFELl2-Sw

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {MdIcon, MdIconRegistry} from  '@angular2-material/icon';
@Component({
    template:
      <md-toolbar>
         <md-icon class="demo-toolbar-icon">menu</md-icon>
         <span>Default Toolbar</span>
         <span class="demo-fill-remaining"></span>
         <md-icon>code</md-icon>
    </md-toolbar>`,
    directives:[MdIcon],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MdIconRegistry]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For using standard icons you just need to put the font into your html (the simplest solution just to use CDN for the font):

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

The other ways are described in docs: http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web

Also you need (as with any other material package) to place material module to NgModule configuration into imports.